# List of compatibles devices AR Core

Tags: arcore

I would like to ask if there is a planned update the list of compatible devices and if they will include the Xiaomi 12T (not pro version) on the next update. Thanks.

Expecting update the list of compatible devices with AR Core.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.